# How to find every possible way to add up a number?

Tags: python, numpy, math, addition

Say I have an integer. Any integer. Arbitrary example: `6`.

Is there a clean way to do perhaps a mesh grid of every possible way to get to `6` in a certain range?

Say `1-9`.

If I have `6`, how can I get an array of `5+1, 2+4, 3+3, 9-3, 7-1, 8-2`, etc.?

Perhaps the output could look like

`[5,1],[2,4],[3,3],[9,3]` etc

Really any way is fine, I can mess around with the output after I figure out a way to actually go about returning that type of function.

Comment: what about 9 / 3 * 2?

Comment: Also 9-3 should mean `[9, -3]` it doesn't belong to range?

Comment: `sum = 6 ;
   result = [(i, 6-i) for i in range(9)]` and filter result to satisfy range condition

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "every possible way to get to `6` in a certain range"? Are you allowing only the sum and difference of two integers in the given range, or are other operations also allowed? And be more clear in the desired output. For example, your given example output leaves out whether the pair of numbers are to be added or subtracted. Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @UmangGupta Thank you, your solution is exactly what I needed. :-)

Comment: @JeffreyEly Sure! I posted that as a solution

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
import math

def get_combinations(number, minimum, maximum):
    ret = []
    for x in range(minimum, math.ceil(number/2)):
        ret.append((x, number - x))
    for x in range(maximum - number):
        ret.append((maximum - x, maximum - (number + x)))
    return ret
```

which returns a `list` of `tuple`s.

Let's walk through:

```
ret = []
```

This is just defining the array to return so we can add stuff to it.

```
for x in range(minimum, math.ceil(number/2)):
```

Cycle through all possible *additive* combinations. What this does is run through this list:

```
(1, x-1), (2, x-2), ..., (n, x-n)
```

However, it only counts up to half of the number (rounded up); this is okay because, for our purposes, `(1, 6)` and `(6, 1)` are the same and we shouldn't include both.

```
ret.append((x, number - x))
```

This is just the Python representation of `(n, x-n)`.

```
for x in range(maximum - number):
```

Cycle through all possible *subtractive* combinations. **This** runs through *this* list:

```
(maximum, maximum - x), (maximum - 1, maximum - (x + 1)), ..., (maximum - n, maximum - (x + n))
```

Onwards!

```
ret.append((maximum - x, maximum - (number + x)))
```

Again, just the Python representation of `(maximum - n, maximum - (x + n))`.

```
return ret
```

And finally, return the completed list.

Answer (score 0):

```
# checks for valid tuple
def valid_tuple(min_val, max_val, x):
    i,j = x
    return i>=min_val and i<=max_val and j>=min_val and j<=max_val

def combinations(sum_val, max_val, min_val):
    result =  [(i, sum_val-i) for i in range(min_val, max_val)]
    result = filter(lambda x: valid_tuple(min_val, max_val, x) , result)
    return list(result) 

combinations (6, 9,0)
# [(0, 6), (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1), (6, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. @user124 was very detailed, both solutions are very much what I need, is there a way I can mark both as the answer to the question? I am going to be using a combination of both.